# Hover state using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I know that hover states can be accomplished via css, that's normally how i prefer to approach them however in this particular case i'm hover over an entire element that has several children and the effect i'm trying to pull off is have all text (whether in a span or p tag) to turn white.

I have a codepen here http://codepen.io/MARS/pen/jlqxK?editors=101 that samples the code and i'm not sure if I can target several elements at once by separating with commas but i tried it in this example.

I have a combination of spans and p tags within the ul i'm trying to target but I feel like i'm not properly targeting all the elements and that's why the text is not changing to white on the hover.

The only text that does currently change to white is the one I declared already in my css.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a similar vein to Jack's answer the jQuery variation would be to use something like:

```
$("#parent").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find("*").addClass('white');
});
```

The `.find("*")` targets all children recursively of the selected element

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this in your CSS:

```
ul.qaUl:hover span.q,p.qP,span.A,p{
  color:#fff;
}
```

If everything under ul.qaUl is supposed to turn white you could do:

```
ul.qaUl:hover *{
   color:#fff;
}
```

Obviously this will only work if your selectors are specific enough to override you other styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think your selector should be this:

```
$('span.q, p.qP, span.genA, p')
```

Apart from this you have css styles which are more specific through cascading so you'll either have to make an as specific white class, or add !important to the color before the semicolon

Obviously this will only work if your selectors are specific enough to override you other styles.

You are also missing ");" at the end of your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

you should be choose between jquery hover or css :hover, if you using all of  them  to change style the same color it's will clash

Comment: Thanks for the tip I think I will try the jquery option to try something new.